# Select query to get data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to run the SQL Select query in my C# code. But I always get the -1 output on

```
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, the same table if I use for `delete` or `insert` works...

`ConnectString` is also fine.

Please check below code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select id from [table1] where name=@zip", conn);

//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip","india");
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// result gives the -1 output.. but on insert its 1
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // iterate your results here
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader["id"]));
}

conn.Close();
```

The query works fine on SQL Server, but I am not getting why only select query is not working.

All other queries are working.

Comment: Why are you executing the command twice?

Comment: exactly Marc and trying to read record without executing `Read()` method.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use stored procedures.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method**

You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.
Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or return values mapped to parameters are populated with data.
For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

**SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method**
Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

**So to get no. of statements returned by SELECT statement you have to use ExecuteScalar method.**

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

So try below code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select id from [table1] where name=@zip", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip","india");
 // int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  if (reader.Read())
  {
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader["id"]));
   }
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: There's no need in closing `reader`, and `reader.Close();` line is redundant since the `reader` will be closed by `using (SqlDataReader reader = ...`

Comment: SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar doesn't return the number of rows affected. It returns "The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference" so it's the best fit for this question I believe.

Answer (score 18):

According to MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

result is ***the number of lines affected***, and since your query is `select` *no lines are affected* (i.e. inserted, deleted or updated) anyhow.

If you want to return a *single row* of the query, use `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`:

```
  int result = (int) (command.ExecuteScalar());
```

However, if you expect *many rows* to be returned, `ExecuteReader()` is the only option:

```
  using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      int result = reader.GetInt32(0);

      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `ExecuteScalar()` in place of `ExecuteNonQuery()` to get a single result
 use it like this

```
Int32 result= (Int32) command.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", result));
```

It will execute the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

As you want only one row in return, remove this use of `SqlDataReader` from your code

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // iterate your results here
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader["id"]));
}
```

because it will again execute your command and effect your page performance.

Answer (score 3):

That is by design.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add parameter also @zip

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
      conn.Open();
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select id from [table1] where name=@zip", conn);
      //
    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
    //
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip","india");
      int result = (Int32) (command.ExecuteScalar());
      using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
          // iterate your results here
       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader["id"]));

      }
      conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ExecuteScalar()` (which returns the first row first column) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` (which returns the no. of rows affected).

You should refer [differences between executescalar and executenonquery](http://www.aspneto.com/ado-net-main-difference-between-executereader-executenonquery-executescalar.html) for more details.

Hope it helps!