# sql command returning boolean for processing in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net, sqlcommand

Is it possible to return a boolean from a sql command -  and then use it C#?

I currently have a database, in which I insert entries. I want before inserting know whether the entry exist, if so do something...

```
private void create_user_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int exist;
    using (DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\toilet\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("WHERE EXIST (SELECT id FROM [information] WHERE id == @given_id)"))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@given_id", create_user_username_textbox.Text));
            command.Connection = connection;
            exist = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(exist));
    }

    //login_screen login = new login_screen();
    //this.Hide();
    //login.ShowDialog();
    //this.Close();

}
```

Doing this gives me a syntax error near `WHERE`  in the `SqlCommand`

Comment: Yes but you don't have a valid SQL command here, just part of a query.

Comment: X-Y ... Are you trying to do an "upsert"? (Update if exists, insert else)

Comment: @Liam the OP doesn't seem to be familiar with SQL in general.

Comment: I am a sql noob...

Comment: change your query to `SELECT 1 FROM [information] WHERE id = @given_id`. Check if it returns 1. if not, it's false.

Comment: *Why* do you want to return a boolean? If the query returns a single ID, you already know there's an existing record. You probably *don't* even need to return anything to the server either - you can write a proper MERGE or UPDATE or INSERT statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select query to get data from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739788/select-query-to-get-data-from-sql-server)

Comment: Assuming you _are_ trying to do an upsert, these links may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql and https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2016/01/05/sql-server-how-to-write-an-upsert-using-merge/

Comment: @Toilet, to generalise on some of the comments here. (Especially if you're not familiar with SQL) Start by writing your queries in SQL Server Management Studio, using hard-coded values or variables to substitute for parameters, until you've got the query you want. **Then, and only then** move the query out into your code - you know you've got something that works that way! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a valid `sql` statement and use `ExecuteScalar` to take some value to compare if it exists. For sample:

```
 using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM [information] WHERE id = @given_id"))
 {
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@given_id", create_user_username_textbox.Text));
     command.Connection = connection;

     // get the result from the sql statement 
     var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

     // if the result is not null, convert it to an integer and compare it. Otherwise it is false (no records).
     exists = result != null ? (int) result > 0 : false;

 }
```

Comment: 1. SQL Server does not support `==`. 2. In this case it's probably OK, but selecting count(*) just to figure out if a single record exists in the table might turn out as a performance killer, if the where clause might return multiple records (but then again, so is my suggestion in the comments).

Comment: Yes @ZoharPeled, thank you for the feedback. I've add some adjusts on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query to check the availability.

```
IF EXIST (SELECT id FROM [information] WHERE id = @given_id) 
SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE 
SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT)
```

Comment: No need to return something like this. The *presence* of a results means yes, there is a record. `1` It's not a boolean either.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos, Agreed. Just modified the query used in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
SELECT id FROM [information] WHERE id == @given_id
```

and call the `SqlCommand` like this:

```
object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

You can set the a bool like:

```
bool valueExists = o != null && o != DBNull.Value;
```