# pass new value from form1 to form2 which was on the same record from the database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

i'm a beginner.
and i just created a login form for Library App.

and my login form consist id, pass, and login button.
here is my login button script.

```
        string userid1 = userid.Text;
        string password1 = userpwd.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id_user,pwd_user from tb_user where id_user='" + userid.Text + "'and pwd_user='" + userpwd.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login success!");
            var myForm = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            myForm.Show();
        }
```

my login table in the database attributes are: id, pass, and name.
can someone tell me or guide me how to pass the id value into name value after i logged into the form 2?

Comment: Surely those passwords aren't in plain text, right?

Comment: no. theres nothing to do with the password right? i just need to put the name of the user who logged in to the form2. maybe in a textbox or label[?]

Comment: You can make static fields in Form2 and assign values to them `Form2.Id  = row['ID'].ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach,

Create public properties in Form2 like,

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And access them from Form1

```
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login success!");
        var myForm = new Form2();
        var row = dt.Rows[0];
        myForm.UserId = Convert.ToString(row["id_user"]);
        myForm.UserName = Convert.ToString(row["name_user"])
        this.Hide();
        myForm.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually do 2 constructors for From2 and a set data/user method in such case:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


public Form2(string id, string name /* other arguments */) : this()
{
   SetUser(id, name);
}


public void SetUser(string id, string name /* other arguments */)
{
    this.Text = $"user logged: {name} ({id})";
    //do stuff
}
```

and invoke that (in your code) like that:

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login success!");
        var myForm = new Form2(id, name /* other arguments */);
        //or:
        //myForm = new Form2();
        //myForm.SetUser(id, name);
        this.Hide();
        myForm.Show();
    }
```

btw: it's not a good idea to store plain text password in the users table.
btw2: for queries it's also a good practice to use parameters, not to build queries from strings sticked together, see it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: theres is nothing to do with sql cmd?

Comment: you need to extract values from the sql command, here you should have more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739788/select-query-to-get-data-from-sql-server