# Ask about start job sql with where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, where-clause, jobs

I have a website C# start job in SQL Server,

```
 string sql = "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'JOB_name'"
```

Job SQL is insert data from view to table

```
INSERT INTO customer SELECT *  FROM v_customer;
```

My web login with username, I got this username.
I want to start job to insert data to table with username, I don't get username login web into SQL Server query.
Can you help me?

```
INSERT INTO customer SELECT *  FROM v_customer where username='Authorization.userDefinition.Username'
```

my job have many query and time to complete job about 3 minute. I dont want run sqlcommand because it made my web is slow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25739883/13687491

Comment: I would always specify the columns, if the table or the view do change their columns, you would not notice of the error until the SQL was executed.

Comment: @nanu_nana: my job have many query and time to complete job about 3 minute. I dont want run sqlcommand because it made my web is slow